# Inserting values based on what column value matches to

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, case

MySQL beginner here. I have two tables (shown below), one (freqs) of which I want to insert value into based on what column the data matches to on the reference column (type_freq below). For instance, 'rs9' (from freqs) has type 'GG', this 'GG' value matches to 'type2' in the type_freq table, and I want to insert the corresponding frequency ('.2' in this case) into the freq value for 'rs9'.

I tried playing around with case statements to no avail. Am I right in thinking this is best solved with several case statements? Is there perhaps a better way? I very much appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

---

Tables:

---

TABLE freqs

```
rsid       type      freq
rs9         GG
rs8         CC
rs1         CC
```

TABLE type_freq

```
 rid       type1    type1_frequency    type2   type2_frequency   type3     type3_frequency
 rs9       AA        .7                GG        .2             GC         .1
 rs8       CC        .5                TT        .3             AT         .2
 rs1       AA        .9                CC        .1             .          .
```

---

My Code:

```
 UPDATE freqs SET req = 
     (
(SELECT type1_Frequency CASE 
    WHEN type.freqs = type1.type_frequencies
            FROM type_frequencies
    END CASE)
(SELECT type2_Frequency CASE
    WHEN type.freqs = type2.type_frequncies
            FROM type_frequencies
    END CASE)
(SELECT type3_Frequency CASE
    WHEN type.freqs = type3.type_frequencies
            FROM type_frequencies
    END CASE)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's design a query which creates a normalized version of your `type_freq` table:

```
SELECT rid, type1 AS type, type1_frequency AS frequency
FROM type_freq
UNION ALL
SELECT rid, type2 AS type, type2_frequency AS frequency
FROM type_freq
UNION ALL
SELECT rid, type3 AS type, type3_frequency AS frequency
FROM type_freq
```

Now let's update your table using this:

```
UPDATE freqs
SET freq =
(
    SELECT frequency
    FROM
    (
        SELECT rid, type1 AS type, type1_frequency AS frequency
        FROM type_freq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT rid, type2 AS type, type2_frequency AS frequency
        FROM type_freq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT rid, type3 AS type, type3_frequency AS frequency
        FROM type_freq
    ) x
    WHERE x.type = freqs.type AND x.rid = freqs.rsid
)
```

Note if you have control over your database schema I would recommend permanently normalizing your `type_freq` table.

Comment: that worked like a charm. Thanks very much for the code and also for the recommendation for permanent normalization. That is a great idea and I will pass it along to the person who has control over it. I really appreciate it!

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but any idea why the query might return the Error: "Subquery returns more than 1 row"?

Comment: @ben There must be two different values for a given {type, rsid} pair.

Comment: I think you're right I added LIMIT 1 to try to remediate the situation. Thanks for all your help